# Integrating Azure AD with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Integrating Azure AD with Xamarin Shows Application is not supported for this API version.
it Shows the Error like this :
 Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 'AADSTS*****: Application '********-****-****-****-***********' is not supported for this API version.